# Back wheel continuously coming loose

Tags: tire, chain, rear-wheel, kickstand

I’m a total amateur when it comes to biking... I recently purchased a new Bergamont Summerville N7 and took it out today for the first time longer than an hour (I’ve had it a week and been to the shops twice with no issues)

However today about 40 mins in the back wheel became incredibly stiff. When I looked I noticed the wheel had shifted position and the tyre was rubbing against the kickstand.

After further investigation it was obvious that the left ‘bolt’ attaching the wheel to the frame was loosening no matter how tightly I fixed it. One of the ‘washers’ is different to the other (which is the one causing an issue)

The one causing an issue also seems to be shearing into the frame itself... I have pics but for some reason this won’t let me upload the images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated before I email the store I purchased from.

Thanks in advance [image][image]

Comment: Would be interested to see the nuts and washers, perhaps one is not serrated, or doesn't have the serrations facing the correct way. Can you indicate in a photo?

Comment: Getting an upvote and bumping your reputation off of 1 may let you upload pics. If not, post them anywhere accessible and put a link in your question, someone will then edit them in for you.

Comment: Hey both, thanks for the advice! Have added some images... the words are pretty much what I’d already written but to a mate lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the washers must be different.
Your bike is equipped with the Shimano Nexus hub. You can find information about the washers here:

https://sheldonbrown.com/nexus-mech.html#washers

The part that is shearing into the frame should actually be in the front, inside the slot, not on the frame.

Actually, they are both facing wrongly the front-rear.

Comment: Ok thanks, so both of these parts should actually be on the front wheel? Do you think the damage is enough to warrant returning the bike? Slightly annoying as you’d expect it to be built correctly by the store mechanics

Comment: @ChrisColley No, sorry, I mean that just the washers, as per your picture, are front/rear, the washers should have the little tab should be rotated to be in front of the axle.
They are on the correct wheel, but rotated 180 degrees wrong.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you @EarlGrey! Incidentally my favourite tea! ☺️

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the hub bearings are wonky and are causing the axle to twist.  This will tend to unscrew the right side fixing bolt.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks. That sounds a bit more serious than the above parts just being the wrong way round... don’t suppose you’d have any tips on how to fix this? I’m completely new to cycling (as an adult) lol

Comment: @ChrisColley - The basic check is to remove the wheel and twist the axle by hand.  It should move smoothly, without much effort.